# How to normalize datetime with Serializer in Symfony5

Tags: csv, symfony, serialization

I'm tring to export data in csv with Serializer. I've a datetime field in my table. How can I convert this date in d/m/Y ?

```
    public function csvExport(ComplaintRepository $repo)
    {
        $serializer = new Serializer([new ObjectNormalizer()], [new CsvEncoder()]);

        $complaints = $repo->findAll();
        $list = $serializer->serialize($complaints, 'csv', [AbstractNormalizer::IGNORED_ATTRIBUTES => ['id', 'registrationdate', 'gdpr', 'langvis', 'department', 'status', 'slug']]);

        echo $list;        

        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
        //it's gonna output in a testing.csv file
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="test.csv"');

        return $response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are using a datetime field in your entity, you can add the `DateTimeNormalizer`, to your `Serializer` to handle it e.g.:

```
 $serializer = new Serializer(
     [
         new DateTimeNormalizer([DateTimeNormalizer::FORMAT_KEY => 'd/m/Y']),
         new ObjectNormalizer(),
     ],
     [new CsvEncoder()]
 );
```